# The convergence or divergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{e^{ax}}{x^b} dx \ (a\in \mathbb R, \ b> 1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

I want to prove the convergence or divergence of $$\int_0^1 \dfrac{e^{ax}}{x^b} dx \ (a\in \mathbb R, \ b> 1)$$

**Roughly** evaluating, I get
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \dfrac{e^{ax}}{x^b} dx
&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{x^b}\left(1+ax+\dfrac{1}{2}a^2x^2+ \dfrac{1}{6}a^3x^3+\cdots \right) dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\dfrac{1}{x^b}+\dfrac{a}{x^{b-1}}+\dfrac{a^2}{2x^{b-2}}+\cdots \right)dx \\
\end{align}

And since the first term $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{x^b} dx$ is $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{x^b} dx=\left[ \dfrac{1}{1-b}\dfrac{1}{x^{b-1}}\right]_0^1=\infty$, I expect that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{e^{ax}}{x^b} dx$ diverges.

But how can I prove this regorously ? I think I can use comparison test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $r\in (0,1)$ such that $e^{ax} >\frac 1 2$ for $0 <x<r$. Now $\int_0^{1} \frac {e^{ax}} {x^{b}}dx>\frac 1 2 \int_0^{r} \frac 1 {x^{b}}dx=\infty$ since $b>1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1 \frac{e^{ax}}{x^b} dx \geq \int_0^{\varepsilon} \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{x^b} dx\geq \int_0^{\varepsilon} \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{x}dx=\infty$$
for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ such that $e^{ax} \geq \frac{1}{2} $ for $x\in[0,\varepsilon]$